# Plotting function on sphere

Tags: matlab, function, plot, geometry

I have a problem with plotting a function on the unit sphere.

The function is given analytically:

```
f = 0.75*exp(-(9*x-2)^2/4 - (9*y-2)^2/4 - (9*z-2)^2/4) + 0.75*exp(-(9*x+1)^2/49-(9*y+1)/10-(9*z+1)/10) + 0.5*exp(-(9*x-7)^2/4 - (9*y-3)^2/4 - (9*z-5)^2/4)-0.2*exp(-(9*x-4)^2 - (9*y-7)^2 - (9*z-5)^2);
```

with x,y,z - points on the sphere. I want to plot it on the sphere, namely stretch it somehow on the unit sphere instead of `surf(x,y,f)`

Comment: Your definition of a sphere (or whatever shape) is strange. `f=...x*...y*...z`. I think it should be something like `0=...x*...y*...z` or `f(x,y)=...x*...y` (which returns the z value)

Answer (score 3):

Even easier, use `sphere`.

```
[x,y,z] = sphere(255);
f = ...
surf(x,y,z,f);
```

Comment: Thank you, but such a representation I know. I will receive a colored sphere, but I also need color+shape. For example, if at some point on sphere I have a value=2 I need to color it with respect to this value and to stretch my sphere in the direction of unit normal twice the original radius. And the same for all values of f.

Comment: A sphere have to be transformed in some "egg" with respect to the above coloring